# How to set up a configured embedder for use of meta filters (-skip) with Serenity, JBehave and Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, bdd, jbehave, serenity-bdd

While creating new scenarios I only want to test the scenario I am currently working with. For this purpose I want to use the `Meta: @skip` tag before my scenarios. As I found out I have to use the `embedder` to configure the used meta tags, so I tried:

```
configuredEmbedder().useMetaFilters(Arrays.asList("-skip"));
```

but actually this still has no effect on my test scenarios. I used it in the constructor of my `SerenityStories` test suite definition. Here is the complete code of this class:

```
public class AcceptanceTestSuite extends SerenityStories {
    @Managed
    WebDriver driver;

    public AcceptanceTestSuite() {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D:/files/chromedriver/chromedriver.exe");
    System.setProperty("chrome.switches", "--lang=en");
    System.setProperty("restart.browser.each.scenario", "true");
    configuredEmbedder().useMetaFilters(Arrays.asList("-skip"));

    runSerenity().withDriver("chrome"); 
    }

    @Override
    public Configuration configuration() {
    Configuration configuration = super.configuration();

    Keywords keywords = new LocalizedKeywords(DEFAULTSTORYLANGUAGE);
    Properties properties = configuration.storyReporterBuilder().viewResources();
    properties.setProperty("encoding", "UTF-8");

    configuration.useKeywords(keywords)
            .useStoryParser(new RegexStoryParser(keywords, new ExamplesTableFactory(new LoadFromClasspath(this.getClass()))))
            .useStoryLoader(new UTF8StoryLoader()).useStepCollector(new MarkUnmatchedStepsAsPending(keywords))
            .useDefaultStoryReporter(new ConsoleOutput(keywords)).storyReporterBuilder().withKeywords(keywords).withViewResources(properties);


    return configuration;
    }
}
```

Is this the wrong place or have I missed something? Still all scenarios are executed.

**EDIT:**

I changed following classes and now I think that it "works"

```
public AcceptanceTestSuite() {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D:/files/chromedriver/chromedriver.exe");
    System.setProperty("chrome.switches", "--lang=de");
    System.setProperty("restart.browser.each.scenario", "true");
    this.useEmbedder(configuredEmbedder());

    runSerenity().withDriver("chrome"); 
}

@Override
public Embedder configuredEmbedder() {
    final Embedder embedder = new Embedder();
    embedder.embedderControls()
        .useThreads(1)
        .doGenerateViewAfterStories(true)
        .doIgnoreFailureInStories(false)
        .doIgnoreFailureInView(false)
        .doVerboseFailures(true);

    final Configuration configuration = configuration();

    embedder.useConfiguration(configuration);
    embedder.useStepsFactory(stepsFactory());
    embedder.useMetaFilters(Arrays.asList("-skip"));

    return embedder;
}
```

But now I get the message  `[pool-1-thread-1] INFO net.serenitybdd.core.Serenity - TEST IGNORED` but the scenario is still executed. Only in the result page I get the info that this scenario is ignored (but still executed). Is there a way to SKIP the scenario so it won't run?

Comment: Where do you write `Meta: @skip` in your .story file? After the `Scenario: ...` line?

Comment: Yes: `Scenario: Here is my scenario description
Meta:
@skip 
Given something
When something
Then something`

Comment: I am experiencing the same issue, and I actually think that is how `SerenityStories` is written — it will look for all the stories in folder, not looking at `metaFilters` of the embedder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could not make it run with using `configuredEmbedder()` but by adding `-Dmetafilter="+working -finished"` as goals in my mvn run configurations and using the tags `@working` for scenarios I'm working with and which I want to run and `@finsihed` for scenarios I don't want to execute. Still I have to change the run configuration if I want to change the meta tags so it is not very comfortable but still I get what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

### Investigation

I debugged the `serenity-jbehave` classes, trying to understand why setting

```
configuredEmbedder().useMetaFilters(Collections.singletonList("-skip"))
```

is not working in all the possible places I put it within my class extending the `SerenityStories`, I found the strategic code place where `metaFilters` in `ExtendedEmbedder#embedder` are overwritten with what we define in our class into settings from `serenity-jbehave`.

This method is `SerenityReportingRunner#createPerformableTree`:

```
private PerformableTree createPerformableTree(List<CandidateSteps> candidateSteps, List<String> storyPaths) {
    ExtendedEmbedder configuredEmbedder = this.getConfiguredEmbedder();
    configuredEmbedder.useMetaFilters(getMetaFilters());
    BatchFailures failures = new BatchFailures(configuredEmbedder.embedderControls().verboseFailures());
    PerformableTree performableTree = configuredEmbedder.performableTree();
    RunContext context = performableTree.newRunContext(getConfiguration(), candidateSteps,
            configuredEmbedder.embedderMonitor(), configuredEmbedder.metaFilter(), failures);
    performableTree.addStories(context, configuredEmbedder.storyManager().storiesOfPaths(storyPaths));
    return performableTree;
}
```

This line changes the set `metaFilters`:

```
    configuredEmbedder.useMetaFilters(getMetaFilters());
```

It overrides the current `metaFilters` value.

Going further the call chain, we get to the logic that defines from where it gets `metaFilters`, i.e. where we can actually set it.

`SerenityReportingRunner#createPerformableTree`

↓

`SerenityReportingRunner#getMetaFilters`

↓

`SerenityReportingRunner#getMetafilterSetting`

This is the method we need!

```
private String getMetafilterSetting() {
    Optional<String> environmentMetafilters = getEnvironmentMetafilters();
    Optional<String> annotatedMetafilters = getAnnotatedMetafilters(testClass);
    Optional<String> thucAnnotatedMetafilters = getThucAnnotatedMetafilters(testClass);
    return environmentMetafilters.orElse(annotatedMetafilters.orElse(thucAnnotatedMetafilters.orElse("")));
}
```

As we see here, the `metaFilters` can be defined in three places, and they override each other. In the priority lowering order, they are:

- Value of `metafilter` (exactly all lowercase!) VM property.
- Value of on `net.serenitybdd.jbehave.annotations.Metafilter` annotation on our `SerenityStories` class.
- Value of on `net.thucydides.jbehave.annotations.Metafilter` annotation on our `SerenityStories` class. This annotation is deprecated, but left in place for backwards-compatibility.

### Solution that is working with the current `serenity-jbehave` version

I've tried/debugged all these three options, they work and override each other as described above.

#### 1. Use environment `metafilter` property

Added this to my JVM run arguments:

```
-Dmetafilter=skip
```

#### 2. Use the modern `@Metafilter` annotation

```
import net.serenitybdd.jbehave.SerenityStories;
import net.serenitybdd.jbehave.annotations.Metafilter;

@Metafilter("-skip")
public class Acceptance extends SerenityStories {
```

#### 3. Use the deprecated `@Metafilter` annotation

```
import net.serenitybdd.jbehave.SerenityStories;
import net.thucydides.jbehave.annotations.Metafilter;

@Metafilter("-skip") // warned as deprecated
public class Acceptance extends SerenityStories {
```

Solution for my current project is to use the current `@Metafilter("-skip")` annotation on my test class, to not depend on/have to change VM properties of the particular Jenkins/local dev execution.

### Possible pull request to make

https://github.com/serenity-bdd/serenity-core/issues/95 — here Serenity guys have suggested me to do a PR with this fix, since they are not concentrated on Serenity + JBehave now.

I understand where to make the changes (in the code chain described above), but I don't know what overriding logic should be:

— MetaFilters from `configuredEmbedder` override any of ENV/annotation MetaFilters.

OR

— Any ENV/annotation MetaFilters override Metafilters from `configuredEmbedder`

OR

— MetaFilters from `configuredEmbedder` are merged with ENV/annotation MetaFilters. This option required merging priority.

Any suggestions?

In any type of fix, I would prefer add the explicit logs about how the overriding is now working into `SerenityReportingRunner#getMetafilterSetting`, since the current behaviour is really non-obvious and took lots of time to investigate.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you document it well (some doc in https://github.com/serenity-bdd/the-serenity-book would be brilliant), I think as a JBehave/Serenity user you are well enough placed to decide which option makes the most sense.